# Default Active Tab in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic1 and need help with figuring out how the default active tab mechanism works.
Currently, there are 3 tabs and the default active tab is the right one.
I would like it to be the left one.

I followed this example - [Ionic : Select Tab - CodePen](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Lszbq) - and the default active tab here is the left one (which is what I want), so I don't understand why in my App the default is the right tab and in the example is the left tab.

Can someone shed some light on the subject?

My Code

article.route.js:

```
.state('app.article', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/article/articleTabs.html',
      })


      .state('app.article.details', {
        url: '/home/:articleID',
          views: {
            'first-tab': {
              templateUrl: 'app/article/article.html',
              controller: 'ArticleController',
              controllerAs: 'vm',
            },
            'second-tab': {
              templateUrl: 'app/article/article.html',
              controller: 'ArticleController',
              controllerAs: 'vm',
            },
            'third-tab': {
              templateUrl: 'app/article/article.html',
              controller: 'ArticleController',
              controllerAs: 'vm',
            }
          }
      });
```

articleTabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab title="First" ui-sref="app.article.details">
    <ion-nav-view name="first-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Second" ui-sref="app.article.details">
    <ion-nav-view name="second-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Third" ui-sref="app.article.details">
    <ion-nav-view name="third-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

article.html:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
    <button class="button button-large ion-ios-location" ng-click="vm.doSomething()">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content has-bouncing="false" overflow-scroll="true">
    ...........
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by giving each tab its own state with specific url and view:

```
.state('app.article.details', {
        url: '/home/:articleID/first',
          views: {
            'first-tab': {
              templateUrl: 'app/article/article.html',
              controller: 'ArticleController',
              controllerAs: 'vm',
            }
          }
      }),
.state('app.article.details', {
        url: '/home/:articleID/second',
          views: {
           'second-tab': {
              templateUrl: 'app/article/article.html',
              controller: 'ArticleController',
              controllerAs: 'vm',
            }
          }
      }),
.state('app.article.details', {
        url: '/home/:articleID/third',
          views: {
           'third-tab': {
              templateUrl: 'app/article/article.html',
              controller: 'ArticleController',
              controllerAs: 'vm',
            }
          }
      });
```

Not sure why or when multiple views should be used though.

Answer (score 1):

It´s simple, just change this line:

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('//the default tab you needed');`

at the end of app.js

Comment: app.js already contains '$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home')', which leads to this state: .state('app.home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
      });                                                                                                       The 'app.article' state is inner state in my app (hope I made myself clear)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the codepen link that your provided in the post defaulted to first tab and jump to third tab after that.

This unexpected behaviour is caused by the following code. Therefore your tab should be defaulted to left if you remove this code.

```
 $timeout( function() {
    $ionicTabsDelegate.select(2, false);    
  },400);
```

Comment: yes, this works fine in the codepen example. But in my app it starts with the third tab as default. I am trying to understand what controls the order. I am not able to have the same behaviour as in the codepen example.